# Find a minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$ from a ladder density function.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables having Lebesgue p.d.f. 
$$f(x;\theta)=\theta I_{\{0<x\le1\}}+(1-\theta) I_{\{1<x<2\}},$$
where $0<\theta<1$. Find a minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Could anybody give some suggestions?

Comment: Try intuitive examples, then you will come up with a solution. If $0< x_1 \leq 1$ and $1<x_2<2$. Then you expect $\theta$ to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Fisher–Neyman factorization theorem, one need to find likelihood function first. Rewrite $f(x;\theta)$ in more convinient form
$$f(x;\theta)=\theta^{I_{\{0<x\le1\}}}(1-\theta)^{I_{\{1<x<2\}}}I_{\{0<x<2\}}.$$

The likelihood function is
$$
f(X_1,\ldots,X_n;\theta)=\underbrace{\theta^{\sum_{i=1}^nI_{\{0<X_i\le 1\}}}(1-\theta)^{\left(n-\sum_{i=1}^nI_{\{0<X_i\le 1\}}\right)}}_{g_\theta\left(\sum_{i=1}^nI_{\{0<X_i\le 1\}}\right)}\underbrace{I_{\{0<X_{(1)}\leq X_{(n)}<2\}}}_{h(X_1,\ldots,X_n)}.
$$

Then $T(X_1,\ldots, X_n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nI_{\{0<X_i\le 1\}}$ is sufficient statistics. It is also a [minimal sufficient statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Minimal_sufficiency).

Comment: Can you explain how the second exponent is obtained in the expression for the likelihood function? I have $\sum_{i=1}^n I_{\{1<X_i<2\}}$ and I am surely missing something simple.

Comment: Nevermind. I see now. $n$ less the the number of $x_i$ in the first interval is equal to the number of $x_i$ in the second.

Comment: Yes, $\sum_{i=1}^n I_{\{1<X_i<2\}}=n-\sum_{i=1}^n I_{\{0<X_i\leq 1\}}$.